# Swap elements from DoublyLinkedList data structure (java)

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

i am new to java programming language. I am storing objects to DoublyLinkedList data structure using my own implementation not the standard java library. I am trying to swap object elements not the Node. Is it possible?

Deck Class

```
DoublyLinkedList<Card> card = new DoublyLinkedList<>();

String[] ranks = {"A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Joker", "Queen", "King"};
String[] suits = {"Club", "Spade", "Diamond", "Heart"};

public Deck() {
    for (String suit : suits) {
        for (String rank : ranks) {
            this.card.insertFirst(new Card(suit, rank));

        }
    }

}

public DoublyLinkedList<Card> getDeck() {
    return card;
}

public void swap() {
    int index1, index2;
    Random generator = new Random();
    Card temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        index1 = generator.nextInt(card.size() - 1);
        index2 = generator.nextInt(card.size() - 1);
        //swap here
    }
}
```

Comment: __I am trying to swap object elements not the Node__. Please explain this line a bit more. Do you just wanted to swap the contents of the two Nodes, instead of the Nodes themselves !!!! And how is this Node represented? What is it's structure?

Comment: Yes, i just want to swap the contents of the two Nodes.

Comment: Tell us what you already tried and what is not working. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: First you need to get the 2 references to target nodes instead of indices. Then swap the values of the 2 nodes.

Comment: @ClarkKent: I still don't understand, the actual question. Though, do try to search for [Copy Constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/q/869033/1057230). Seems like this is what you trying to get at :-)

Comment: I just want to swap the data of the nodes in a random fashion. @nIcEcOw